# Angular NGRX / Reactive Form and ngOnChanges timing issue

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngonchanges

Angular 9

I'm trying to use ngOnchanges to trigger the load to my form. The data for the form is coming from an @input from the shell-component.

The problem I have is ngOnChanges is firing BEFORE ngOnit and the form has not been built yet for the data to populate.

Playing around with it I have put in a temporary fix with a setTimeout, but its not ideal

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 setTimeout(() => {
    // patch form with value from the store
    if (changes.profile) {
      const profile: IProfile = changes.profile.currentValue;
      this.displayProfile(profile);
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

The timeout even with 0 delay is enough for the form to catch up. If I don't put in the delay the data is loaded before the form is built and triggers an error with no data.

This seems pretty fundamental. what I am missing?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you need `ngOnChanges`? Is the input value coming from the store?

Comment: yes, ngOnChanges is convenient to handle any changes of state back to the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with a setter on the **@Input()** without needing **ngOnChanges**:

```
@Input()
set profile(profile) {
  this.displayProfile(profile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of these very useful patterns described in answer below:

[how to stop ngOnChanges Called before ngOnInit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111474/how-to-stop-ngonchanges-called-before-ngoninit)

Comment: The bool solution didn't work for me. SimpleChanges with isFirstChange either. Frankly setting a SetTimeout is cleaner than the hassle of a new subject.

Comment: Well... try the others, especially: the SimpleChanges API one: `!changes["bar"].isFirstChange()`

Comment: My point is that this is pretty fundamental, but it requires fiddling. I went through the documentation and couldn't find a unified approach.